# What does the (number of) cookies sent to server depend on?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, cookies

While working on a web application with struts, I came across the following situation.

Consider the following to links:

`<s:a href="action1.action" id="link1" ></s:a>` and `<s:a href="#" id="link2" onclick="submitData();"></s:a>`

the function `submitData()` is defined as follows:

```
function submitData(){

      var var1="x"
      $("#targetDiv").load("action1.action",{someVar:var1 });

}
```

What I discovered when hitting the links is that the number of cookies sent to the action is different. What can cause that difference?

Comment: I don't see any cookies in your code at all. Can you show us where you use them, and which sets of cookies your server receives in the different requests?

Comment: Bergi , I set the cookies from within my action via ActionServletContext.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per cookies definition, some some of them could be set to work in different URL paths:

> The cookie domain and path define the scope of the cookie—they tell
>   the browser that cookies should only be sent back to the server for
>   the given domain and path. If not specified, they default to the
>   domain and path of the object that was requested...

[Wikipedia Article about cookies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie)